# Why using select boxes with data-native-menu="false" in chained dialogs generates url hashes that leads to closing the current dialog?

Tags: jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-dialog

I use chained dialog boxes to collect some input data. Every dialog has a select box, a next button and a popup menu that enables the user to jump back to every dialog in the chain before the current one.

On a startpage a button opens the first dialog box. When you select an entry from the select box and go over to the next dialog by clicking the next-button everything works fine. Jumping back to the first dialog by selecting the entry in the popup-menu also works fine. But after clicking again on the next-button to get back to the second dialog, selecting an entry in its select-box leads to closing the dialog and showing the startpage again.

Why is that? I think it has something to do with the ui-state=dialog-URL-adds in the hash ([issue 949](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/949)), [issue 1030](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1030))

I use data-native-menu="false" in my select boxes. When I use the default data-native-menu="true" everything works fine.

JQ V1.8.2
JQM V1.2.0
Tested in FF, Safari

I also started an [issue ticket on the JQM githup page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5177).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned ticket brought the solution. This behaviour will be fixed in the next release. [Here](http://jsbin.com/uzaret/350/edit) you can test my problem and [here](http://jsbin.com/uzaret/349/edit) you can try the solution that brings the next release.

By the way: In the meantime you can use this piece of code to make the current release work:

```
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
```